# Is disposable in "doOnSubscribe" method and the disposable returned by "subscribe" method are different?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a BaseViewModel as:

```
public class BaseViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<ApiError> apiError = new MutableLiveData<>();
private MutableLiveData<ApiProgress> apiProgress = new MutableLiveData<>();
private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

// Emit "progress's start" on subscribe and "progress's end" on after success or error.
// Add this to the observable action sequence with ".compose(baseTransformer())" before subscribe.
<T> SingleTransformer<T, T> baseTransformer() {
    return upstream -> upstream
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {
                Log.d("dis", "doOnSubscribe : " + disposable + " " + disposable.isDisposed());
                compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
                apiProgress.setValue(ApiProgress.start());
            })
            .doOnDispose(() -> Log.d("dis", "I am disposed.."))
            .doFinally(() -> apiProgress.setValue(ApiProgress.stop()))
            .doOnError(err -> {
                apiError.setValue(ApiError.create(err));
            });
}

public LiveData<ApiError> getApiError() {
    return apiError;
}

public LiveData<ApiProgress> getApiProgress() {
    return apiProgress;
}

@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    super.onCleared();
    if (!compositeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
        compositeDisposable.dispose();
        Log.d("dis", "compositeDisposable disposed");
    }
}
}
```

and a LoginViewModel as:

```
public class LoginViewModel extends BaseViewModel {

Disposable disposable;
private AuthRepository authRepository;
private MutableLiveData<Login> loginData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public LoginViewModel() {
    authRepository = new AuthRepository();
}

public LiveData<Login> getLoginData() {
    return loginData;
}

public void login(String userName, String password) {
    disposable = authRepository.login(userName, password)
            .compose(baseTransformer())
            .subscribe(login -> loginData.setValue(login), err -> {
            });
}

@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    super.onCleared();
    Log.d("dis", "LoginViewModel : " + disposable + " " + disposable.isDisposed());
}
}
```

I want to dispose the disposable returned by subscribe method but I want to do it in transformation function so, I don''t need to do it every time.

I got following output in Logs:

```
D/dis: doOnSubscribe : null false
D/dis: compositeDisposable disposed
D/dis: LoginViewModel : 0 false
```

Please help me in understand: why the disposable not disposed even after compositeDisposable disposed successfully.

Comment: `doOnSubscribe` is there to allow peeking into the subscription process and potentially capture the upstream **at that point** for inspection, i.e., debugging purposes. So do you see the pattern with `doOnError` etc. now?

Comment: I didn't see any pattern. I just want to achieve: Any disposable should be captured by `compositeDisposable` in `BaseViewModel` so `LoginViewModel` or any other ViewModel do not need to check for disposing a disposable.

Comment: Above, I want to capture the `disposable` in `doOnSubscribe` method as I was not able to capture it by any other way. Do you have any idea to achieve this ?

Comment: Why? Save the `Disposable` returned by the `subscribe`. There is no reason for you to use `doOnSubscribe`.

Comment: Sounds like you already decided. I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this goal by adding a new method

```
<T> void consumeApi(Single<T> apiSingle, Consumer<T> consumer) {
    compositeDisposable.add(apiSingle
            .compose(baseTransformer())
            .subscribe(accept(consumer))
    );
}
```

in BaseViewModel. Now I just need to call

```
consumeApi(
            authRepository.login(userName, password),
            login -> loginData.setValue(login)
    );
```

in LoginViewModel.